# Рекурсивно скачать сайт с помощью wget.py

Tags: python-3.x, wget

Как с помощью пакета wget в python скачать сайт целиком?
вроде в *nix есть -r

Comment: А зачем Python?) Можно просто с помощью wget скачать

Comment: `wget --header "Cookie: uid=*; sid=*;" -r -k -l 7 -p -E -nc -H -D ru.stackoverflow.com https://ru.stackoverflow.com/`